# "404 - An error has occurred. Component not found" error while i select my component from menu in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

I have a custom component contactList to show list of contacts from DB . This works fine and list gets displayed in localhost when i call index.php?option=com_componentList . But now i uploaded the project to the live server . In live server I am getting this 404 error . Other built in components are working perfectly . What could be the reason ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: When you say "uploaded", do you simply mean you uploaded the folder for your component? If so then this you have to make sure you install the component properly so that everything gets registered in the database

Comment: ya , i simply uploaded my folder to live server ...... So i need to uninstall the uploaded component and install the component again at live server , ryt ?

Comment: But when i try to install at live server , I am getting an error message " JFTP: :mkdir: Bad response " ....my ftp is enabled at live

Comment: any suggestion Lodder .... I cant install at server .....should i give 777 permission to all folders ?

Comment: All folders should be 755 and files should be 644, never use 777. Ensure all the necessary folder have 755 then installation should work]